# jQuery/Tablesorter: maintain secondary alphabetical sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table of names and ages that I want the user to be able to sort. When the page initally loads, `sortList` lists the rows in order from oldest to youngest, and then secondarily from A to Z.

I want the same thing (a SECONDARY alphabetical sort) when the user actually clicks on the age `<th>`, but `sortForce` is making the alphabetical sort primary. Is there an alternative?

```
$('#super_results table').tablesorter({
    sortForce: [[0,0]],
    sortList: [[1,1],[0,0]]
});
```

Or am I misunderstanding `sortForce`? [Documentation here.](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-sort-force.html)

**Update:** I couldn't find a plugin to do this for me, so I wrote some code that sorts the multidimensional array that builds the table. If you have an array called `tableContents`, and `tableContents[0]` is a subarray of names and `tableContents[1]` is a subarray of ages, then calling `tableContents.sort(numSort)` will sort the array first from oldest to youngest, and then from A to Z. (`num2Sort` sorts youngest to oldest first.) Then you can recreate the table using `createHtml(data)`, and use the result to replace the old table.

```
function numSort(a, b) {
    if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        if (a[0] === b[0]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return (a[1] < b[1]) ? 1 : -1;
}

function num2Sort(a, b) {
    if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        if (a[0] === b[0]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return (a[1] < b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}

function createHtml(data) {
    var completeListLength = MYAPP.completeList.length,
    html = '<table>';
    html += '<thead>';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<th>names</th>';
    html += '<th>ages</th>';
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '</thead>';
    html += '<tbody>';
    for (var i = 0; i < completeListLength; i += 1) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' + data[i][0] + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + data[i][1] + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    html += '</tbody>';
    html += '</table>';
    return html;
}
```

Comment: How does it work when you remove sortForce?

Comment: When I remove sortForce and click on ages, the table sorts the ages but there's no alphabetization.

Comment: I don't the plugin has the ability to do what you are asking..

Comment: OK, I'll look for another one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem, and stumbled upon this:

[jQuery tablesorter secondary sorting problem](http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/443/jquery-tablesorter-secondary-sorting-problem)

Comment: Already wrote my own code for my specific table, but thanks! This should definitely help other people who encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with tablesorter, but by looking at the documentation, it appears the sortForce property locks down a column to a specific order -- which then allows for sorting of other columns secondarily.  I don't think that's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The link in first answer is broken. Here's a link to webarchive of this page.

[jQuery tablesorter secondary sorting problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20130221043604/http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/443/jquery-tablesorter-secondary-sorting-problem)

I had slightly modified this code to work in v.2.22.3 (maybe will work in other versions)

Cut these lines from the tablesorter's code:

```
if (c.sortForce !== null) {
    arry = c.sortForce;
    for (col = 0; col < arry.length; col++) {
        if (arry[col][0] !== indx) {
            c.sortList.push(arry[col]);
        }
    }
}
```

And paste it after `c.sortList.push([ indx, order ]);` - some lines below the place with previous code.
Tablesorter v.2.0 had another names for variables (for c => config, indx => i, etc.) but you can find the right place searching for `sortForce` - it has several appearances in the code of Tablesorter